# mysql IF column EXISTS THEN delete record from table

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I need to delete a record from a table if columnID=X, but only from tables that have columnID.

```
$query = "show tables" ;
list($selCount,$tables,$selError) = dbSelect($query,array()) ;
foreach ($tables as $table) {
  $tableName = $table['Tables_in_dbName'] ;
  $query = "IF EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns 
            WHERE table_name = '$tableName' 
               AND column_name='cID' 
               AND table_schema= DATABASE()
        ) THEN DELETE FROM $tableName WHERE cID=?;
        END IF;" ;
  list($delCount,$delError) = dbDelete($query,array($corpID)) ;
}
```

Something is wrong with the IF EXISTS...THEN portion of my query but I am not understanding what.  I have read many other examples of IF EXISTS and can't see what I am doing wrong.

Specifically, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'clubTabl' at line 1
```

I have tested the inner portion of the query, the `SELECT` part, and its working fine, so something is wrong related to the `IF EXISTS`

Comment: what do you mean by "something is wrong"?

Comment: Have you tried a merge?

Comment: @jeiv - no, not certain how to do that based on the need to delete certain records.

Comment: @rolinger you can't use If statements outside procs , you need to make a proc , put your code there and call the proc

Comment: @eshirvana - I just read about IF/THENs as stored procedures within mysql which is leading to more questions about how/when/where to create and use stored procedures.  I am certain all for the good to learn something new.  But for the task at hand. Is there another method I could use to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another method that seems much more simple:

```
$query = " select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name='cID'" ;
list($selCount,$tables,$selError) = dbSelect($query,array()) ;
foreach ($tables as $table) {
  $tableName = $table['table_name'] ;
  $query = "DELETE FROM $tableName WHERE cID=?" ;
  list($delCount,$delError) = dbDelete($query,array($corpID)) ;
}
```